# Count the number of words in the line beginning with a particular word

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to count the number of words in a particular line which contains a specific ID (e.g. *AUY). So far I have tried using the below regex for finding the line but it does not consider the "*" at the start

```
^ *(.*\b(?:\\*AUY)\b.*) *$
```

I have below test string

```
*AUY:   today is holiday so Peter and Mary do not need to go to work .
%mor:   n|today cop|be&3s n|holiday conj|so n:prop|Peter conj|and n:prop|Mary v|do neg|not v|need inf|to v|go prep|to n|work .
%snd:   <00:00:00><00:07:37>
%AUY:   ok_pfp (0.40) er today is holiday errfr ::: so er Peter and Mary {is} ~ er do not need errfr ::: to go to work . errfr :;:a |
```

The result should be only first string but it returns first and last string in result matches.
See this [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/WxQAKkiaXj)

Comment: Can you make your question more clear? What are you trying to extract from the test string that you have provided?

Comment: You can just do `string.split(' ').length`

Comment: Your script right now is just (trying) to match the string, but not counting the words. All you need to match the string is `^\*AUY.*`. Is this all you are looking for? What code have you tried for *counting* the number of words in the string?

Comment: There are two problems with this regex: (1) `\b` matches word boundaries, but the character `*` is not a word character so the boundary before it isn't matched; (2) to match an asterisk, use `\*` (`\\*` matches zero or more backslashes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that:

```
/^.*?\*AUY:(.*?)$/gmi
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/IZhwZa/3)

1. ^ asserts position at start of a line
2. .*? matches any character (except for line terminators)
3. *? Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times (lazy)
4. \* matches the character *
5. AUY: matches the characters AUY
6. .*? matches any character (except for line terminators)
7. $ asserts position at the end of a line
8. g modifier: global. don't return after first match
9. m modifier: multi line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of
   each line (not only begin/end of string)
10. i modifier: insensitive

[Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/JwoHiwYCDx)

Code Sample:

```
function countWord(){

const regex = /^.*?\*AUY:(.*?)$/gmi;
const str = `*AUY:  today is holiday so Peter and Mary do not need to go to work .
%mor:   n|today cop|be&3s n|holiday conj|so n:prop|Peter conj|and n:prop|Mary v|do neg|not v|need inf|to v|go prep|to n|work .
%snd:   <00:00:00><00:07:37>
%AUY:   ok_pfp (0.40) er today is holiday errfr ::: so er Peter and Mary {is} ~ er do not need errfr ::: to go to work . errfr :;:a |`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    alert(m[1].match(/\b(\w+)\b/g).length);
}

    }
```

Comment: Thanku Maverick ,it worked .But can you please explain how I can loop through all these matched lines and count the words in it ?

Comment: @BilalHussain your question should have been more clear, now i have understood that you want to count the number of words after the AUY: please watch out my updated sample code

Comment: Thanku soo much Maverick that was what I was exactly looking for :)

Answer (score 3):

Let `x` be your string. Then

```
(x.match(/(^|\n)\*AUY[^\r\n]*/g) || [])
    .map(
        function(s) { return s.match(/\S+/g).length; }
    );
```

Will return an array of the number of word-like constructs within the respective lines which begin with the string '*AUY'.

Explanation:

The regular expression looks for the string *AUY at the beginning of the string or directly after any newline (i.e., at the beginning of a line even if that line is not at the beginning of the string), as well as any non-CRLF characters following that first token of *AUY (i.e., the rest of that line).

The idiom `|| []` after a match is performed will return an empty array if the match value is `null`, thus preventing an error when an array is expected instead of a null value.

The final step `.map` operates on each element of the matched array and counts the non-whitespace matches and returns these counts as a new array. Note that we do not need to protect this match with the `|| []` idiom because a null match is impossible, due to the fact that the line contains at minimum the non-whitespace string *AUY.

You can work with this code as a starting point to do what you actually want to do. Good luck!

Comment: Thanku Joesph that was of great help but I want to count the characters after " *AUY:    ". Right now it is counting in the string like this ("↵*AUY: suddenly she yell and said the light bulb is burning out .") with the return of 13 for a given match.

Comment: @BilalHussain Lol, you're welcome! All you do is subtract 1. `return s.match(/\S+/g).length - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

use the following regex,

```
(^.*\*AUY.*$)
```

You can [check it here](https://regexper.com/#(%5E.*%5C*AUY.*%24)%0A)